# Transformar todos os elementos de uma lista em floats

Tags: python, string, loop, float

Esse é o código que eu escrevi.

```
n_alunos=input('')
x=0
idades=[]
alturas=[]

while x != n_alunos:
    x+=1
    n=raw_input('')
    a=n.split(" ")
    idades.append(a[0])
    alturas.append(a[1])
```

Como transformo os elementos das 2 listas de string para float ?

Answer (score 5):

Pra converter uma lista já existente de strings em uma lista de floats:

```
lista = [float(i) for i in lista]
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614236/in-python-how-do-i-convert-all-of-the-items-in-a-list-to-floats

A conversão tbm pode ser realizada direto no append:

```
idades.append(float(a[0]))
```

Reescreví seu código pra python3 realizando a conversão assim(e algumas outras modificações).Se preferir:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
n_alunos = int(input('N. de alunos:    '))
idades = []
alturas = []
for i in range(n_alunos):
    dados = input('Idade/altura:    ').split(" ")
    idades.append(float(dados[0]))
    alturas.append(float(dados[1]))
```

Comment: map(float, lista) também é uma boa